# draw artists over seaborn facetGrid

Tags: pandas, seaborn

I would like to draw arrows over all panels of a facetGrid.

In this dummy example, I want to draw the same arrow on all panels:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pylab as plt


datDf=pd.DataFrame({'values':np.random.randint(0,100,100)})
datDf['group']=np.random.randint(0,5,100)
g = sns.FacetGrid(datDf, col="group",
                  col_wrap=3,
                  size=4.5,
                  sharex=True, sharey=True, despine=False)
g.map(plt.plot,'values')

for ax in g.axes:
    arrow=plt.arrow(0,0,50,50,width=5,
            length_includes_head=True,
            head_width=5*2,
            color='gray')
    ax.add_artist(arrow)
```

I am receiving this error:

ValueError: Can not reset the axes.  You are probably trying to re-use an artist in more than one Axes which is not supported

What is the correct way to draw artists on facetGrids?

Comment: http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/axis_grids.html#mapping-custom-functions-onto-the-grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ax.arrow` instead of `plt.arrow` to draw an arrow on the axes.

This should work:

```
for ax in g.axes:
    ax.arrow(0,0,50,50,width=5,
            length_includes_head=True,
            head_width=5*2,
            color='gray')
```